# Why does Buddhism last so long into the future in Hinduism, while the other religions seem missing?

Tags: scripture, other-religions, future

"Buddhists" are mentioned in the far future in multiple places like the Kalki and Bhavishya Puranas. This is over 400,000 years in the future for the Kalki Purana, so they can't be Buddhists as we know them.

Anyway, does scripture or any guru given an explanation for why Buddhism lasts so much longer than the other non-Hindu faiths, who don't appear as a faith practiced?

https://www.pdfdrive.com/bhavishya-purana-bhavishya-maha-purana-pratisarg-parv-khand-three-full-translated-to-english-d179134516.html

https://cloudup.com/cws97nPY2uD

Comment: This is not a question about the Hindu religion. See the forum rules.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda It is about the Hindu religion. It's about what happens to Buddhism according to Hinduism.

Comment: @ruben2020 It's clear from chapter headings if you want to see for yourself

Comment: It is not clear if other religions will survive according to our scriptures thus your question is superseded.

Comment: @Wikash_ I don't think the Abrahamic religion followers are stupid enough to believe in their faiths when raised in a world with giant Rakshasa women in the sky disproving them. I'm not sure that level of stupidity is possible.

Comment: Well, what you think as Rakshasa Christians may interpret it differently. In this current world Christianity is dominant yet our scriptures remain silent on this. So it would not suprise me that in the future Christianity will remain dominant.

Comment: @Wikash_ While Christianity has an unfeasible if the religion is true number of insanely overpowered villains, none of them closely resemble a Rakshasa.

Comment: @Wikash_ I feel like others call Christianity: Overpowered Villains, The Religion

Comment: They are still in greater numbers and continue to grow. There are no signals in our scriptures that that will be different in the future.

Comment: @Wikash_ Only the Abrahamic religions are in greater numbers. Their scriptures indicate they don't with future events. Even if they don't happen naturally, someone powerful could get annoyed at them, fudge them in an annoying, for them, way. Then they would just sit back and watch the sects tear themselves apart over trying to reconcile their scriptural prophecy will conclusions they don't like.

Comment: Someone powerful could fudge them away? Sorry sir: real life is not a cartoon. It looks like Christianity will stay dominant for time to come. Sorry to break it to you.

Comment: @Wikash_ Well if real life being that way is a cartoon, I guess Christianity is believing in a cartoon.

Comment: I meant your view of life when it concerns Christianity seem cartoonish. The number of Christians is outperforming Hindus and is increasing by the day. This is in conflict with our scriptures stating that belief in God will dimish in the Kali yuga. The number of Christians will most likely keep on growing.

Comment: @Wikash_ Where do they say belief in God will decrease? They say a lot of things about Kali Yuga, but I've never heard them say that.

Comment: @Wikash_ Belief in God is overrated anyway. Do you really think he will count not believing in the world and worldview around him as believing in him? Would you count someone believing in you in the world of Pokemon as believing in you?

Comment: I do not understand your last two questions. As for your first question: https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/12-16/

Comment: @Wikash_ The word used for "atheist" more accurately means heretical (i.e. still claiming belief). It would be kind of odd for the word for Atheist to not refer to God. https://www.wisdomlib.org/definition/pashanda

Comment: If you look more closely in your link it says unbeliever.

Comment: @Wikash_ Heretics are in a sense unbelievers.

Comment: I think this is about non believers.

Answer (score 1):

You make the mistake of equating a Buddha with Buddhist. The Buddha of our time did not create Buddhism - Buddhism was created by his followers. The word "Buddha" is simply a Sanskrit word that means Awakened or Enlightened.

In Sanskrit, names always only represent the properties which the object/Being possesses. Because of this, every incarnation of Vishnu, Shiva, etc - would all by definition classify as Buddhas, although they are definitely greater than just a simple Buddha. So for someone to be labeled Buddha, it is a statement that they are enlightened/awakened. That's just what the word means.

Likewise this is the reason many people consider Gautama Buddha to have been an incarnation of Vishnu. However again do note that Buddha != Buddhist. Buddhism was created by Gautama's followers, Buddha himself didn't have a significant role in developing what is called Buddhism today - rather his followers wrote down what he spoke.

Naturally because none of his followers are Buddhas themselves, the teachings inevitably become distorted overtime - this is inevitable because formal "Buddhas" only come into the world to restore the teachings. For example consider the modern buddhist idea of "no self" - the Buddha never taught any such idea, rather he only taught what the self isn't, and even explicitly stated that after all those non-self properties are eliminated, there remains a transcendental awareness.

So, contrary to popular belief, Buddha himself really didn't contradict Hinduism much at all, rather that blame is on his followers and the general decline of the dharma overtime. It's also important to remember that during the time of the Buddha, there was no such thing as "Hinduism", rather there were just the Vedic texts and practices. The primary opposition Buddha had was against the animal sacrifices, which we know arose in the Treta Yuga due to the decline of righteousness and knowledge. All incarnations of Vishnu would be against animal sacrifices by His very nature due to the fact that it represents a lowly practice that arose from loss of knowledge.

Basically there's no problem with Buddha's themselves, only with followers that distort the teachings. The word Buddha is simply a Vedic Sanskrit word that means awakened/enlightened one.

Comment: Well that just leads to the question who are the "Buddhists" and why are they called that?

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa Well, there's a problem - the Kalki Paruna is greatly mistranslated - many words that were translated to "buddhist" mean "red one" or "red clothed one" - translator assumes it means Buddhist red robes. However research reveals many of those same words refer to "clothing stained red with blood". Since the story says Kalki plunders their wealth afterwards, they are merchants who murder. Buddhist have no wealth nor would they fight back if someone tried kill them usually. So, it is certain that that any translation which implies Kalki kills Buddhist is certainly wrong.

Comment: @AupakaranaAbhibhaa I haven't looked into the Bhavishya Purana yet, but in general I would say if something sounds fishy/odd, then research the original text language because it may be translated wrong. It is not uncommon for religious texts to be intentionally mistranslated for the purpose of propaganda, perhaps by corrupt leaders or otherwise. It's a problem with all religious texts. The Bible, Sanskrit texts, etc. For example, Christianity is known for being "anti-gay", however all the verses about that were wrongly translated from the Hebrew and had nothing to do with homosexuality.